# Spring Boot Mongo update nested array of documents

Tags: spring-boot, mongodb-query, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I'm trying to set an attribute of a document inside an array to uppercase.

This is a document example

```
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5e786a078bc3b3333627341e"),
    "test": [
        {
          "itemName": "alpha305102992",
          "itemNumber": ""
        },
        {
          "itemName": "beta305102630",
          "itemNumber": "P5000"
        },
        {
          "itemName": "gamma305102633 ",
          "itemNumber": ""
        }]
  }
```

I already tried a lot of thing.

```
    private void NameElementsToUpper() {
        AggregationUpdate update = AggregationUpdate.update();

    //This one does not work
              update.set("test.itemName").toValue(StringOperators.valueOf(test.itemName).toUpper());
    
    //This one also
              update.set(SetOperation.set("test.$[].itemName").withValueOfExpression("test.#this.itemName"));

    //And every variant in between these two. 
    // ...

          Query query = new Query();
          UpdateResult result = mongoTemplate.updateMulti(query, update, aClass.class);

          log.info("updated {} records", result.getModifiedCount());
    }
```

I see that Fields class in spring data is hooking into the "$" char and behaving special if you mention it. Do not seem to find the correct documentation.

EDIT: Following update seems to work but I do not seem to get it translated into spring-batch-mongo code

```json
db.collection.update({},
[
  {
    $set: {
      "test": {
        $map: {
          input: "$test",
          in: {
            $mergeObjects: [
              "$$this",
              {
                itemName: {
                  $toUpper: "$$this.itemName"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Any solutions?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For now I'm using which does what i need. But a spring data way would be cleaner.

```
mongoTemplate.getDb().getCollection(mongoTemplate.getCollectionName(Application.class)).updateMany(
            new BasicDBObject(),
            Collections.singletonList(BasicDBObject.parse("""
                    {
                        $set: {
                            "test": {
                                $map: {
                                    input: "$test",
                                    in: {
                                        $mergeObjects: [
                                            "$$this",
                                            {
                                                itemName: { $toUpper: "$$this.itemName" }
                                            }
                                        ]
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    """))
    );
```